# Delete empty Spaces in String Array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have the following Array in JavaScript:

```
["X1", "         X2", "      X3", "      X4", "      X5", "      X6", "      X YZ1", "       X YZ2", "       X7", "      X8", "      X9"]
```

I would like to delete the empty spaces before a letter is beginning, see for example X2. But I would like that the space between X and YZ1 is not deleted.

Does anybody know, how I can do that?

Thank you in advance.

Greets.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegEx to replace leading whitespace:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/^\s+/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try, replace()

```
strArray[0].replace(/\s/g, "") ;
```

Comment: Second one fails `space between X and YZ1 is not deleted`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
array[i] = array[i].trim();
}
```

Comment: trim() removes whitespace from both sides of a string.

Answer (score 0):

here is working solution, that adds a new method to Array object.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bnpeon25/

```
a = ["X1", "         X2", "      X3", "      X4", "      X5", "      X6", "      X YZ1", "       X YZ2", "       X7", "      X8", "      X9"];

Array.prototype.trimvals = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        this[i] = this[i].replace(/^\s+/, "");
    }
    return this;
}

console.log(a.trimvals());
```

Answer (score 0):

All modern browsers natively support `.trim()`. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

```
arr[i] = arr[i].trim();
```

This will not delete the embedded spaces as you stated in your question.

Alternatively, if you want to get rid of all spaces: leading, trailing and embedded; then you could you regex:

```
arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/\s/g, "");
```

***Snippet using `.trim()` (Leading and Trailing Spaces):***

```js
var arr = ["X1", "         X2", "      X3", "      X4", "      X5", "      X6", "      X YZ1", "       X YZ2", "       X7", "      X8", "      X9"];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { arr[i] = arr[i].trim(); }
document.getElementById("result").innerText = arr.join(",");
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

***Snippet using `regex` (Simple all spaces):***

```js
var arr = ["X1", "         X2", "      X3", "      X4", "      X5", "      X6", "      X YZ1", "       X YZ2", "       X7", "      X8", "      X9"];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/\s/g, ""); }
document.getElementById("result").innerText = arr.join(",");
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```